# C# HTTPClient Not Sending Request

Tags: c#, wpf, dotnet-httpclient

I have a WPF application where I need to retrieve configuration data from a remote API. The API has been tested and is working correctly returning what I believe to be the correct format. I have created a data type for the response etc etc but when I get to the line getting the response via the HttpClient it doesn't send any request to the API.

DataType :-

```
public class Mylist
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemText { get; set; }
        public string ConfigName { get; set; }
        public string ConfigValue { get; set; }
        public string ConfigType { get; set; }
    }
```

Code :-

```
string licKey = ConfigManager.GetSetting("Lic");
            string Uri = ConfigManager.GetSetting("API");
            string UserAPI = ConfigManager.GetSetting("Config");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Uri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync(UserAPI + "?Licence=" + licKey);
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Mylist>>();
            int count = 0;
            List<Mylist> nudges = new List<Mylist>((IEnumerable<Nudgelist>)data);
// Do something with the data
```

the code builds the correct URL (https://example.com/api/Uri?Licence=licencevalue) for the request and if input manually into the browser it gives a response as per the below :-

```
<Mylist>
<ConfigName>cName</ConfigName>
<ConfigType>cType</ConfigType>
<ConfigValue>cValue</ConfigValue>
<ItemName>iName</NudgeName>
<ItemText>iText</NudgeText>
</Mylist>
<Mylist>
...
</Mylist>
```

When I run the code above and step through it then we get to the line "var response = await client.GetAsync(UserAPI + "?Licence=" + licKey);" and it just skips the rest of the code and moves onto the next call, no error raised or failures anywhere to be found.

I have run logs on the API and we are not seeing the request coming in, if we use an identical model of code for calling another API controller to call Uri2 (https://example.com/api/Uri2?Licence=licencevalue) it works fine.

Comment: You don't check the status code on the response, so how can you be sure there's no failure?

Comment: Can you pls post the Uri and UserApi you got from config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MyList>>(stringData);
}
else 
{
    var statusCode= response.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this is now firing the request to the API and running correctly.